# Is there any Query Builder with Graphical Interface for WSO2 Stream Processor?

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am looking for an **Open source Business Intelligent (BI)**  Solutions for my organization. So I am trying **WSO2 Stream Processor** and I could not find any graphical Interface for building RDBMS Queries.

I check editor, portal and widgets.

widgets were very nice for visualizing data but samples were limited and I could not find what I am looking for.

Especially I need an Interface that shows me my DB (or multiple DBs) and when I select Them to show me Tables and I Could select Tables and building my query graphically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this is not available in the Editor/Tooling interface. However, it will be easier if this can be viewed on the Editor itself. You can raise a feature request in [Siddhi distribution](https://github.com/siddhi-io/distribution) repo and the team will see if we can incorporate it into the roadmap.

Please note, WSO2SP is not currently under active development and you can try the latest [WSO2 Streaming Integrator](https://github.com/wso2/streaming-integrator) or OSS option of [Siddhi Cloud-native Stream Processor](https://siddhi.io/). However, Streaming Integrator focuses on streaming data integration. Whereas Siddhi Cloud-native Stream Processor bundles the newest version of Siddhi and it's a tool for building fully-fledged event-driven applications.